# Parse logfile can collect values

Tags: bash

I would like to scan a long printout and take the value of the printout 
between the START and END and put 'NA' if the values are not available. 
Example file as below.

I want to do this in the Bash Cygwin.

```
logfile.txt:

START

label1 label2 label3
valueA valueB valueC

label4 label5
valueD valueE

label6
valueF

END

START

label1 label3
valueG valueH

label6
valueI

END

START

label1
valueJ

label6
valueK

END
```

The wanted output.txt is below

```
valueA valueB valueC valueD valueE valueF
valueG NA     valueH NA     NA     valueI
valueJ NA     NA     NA     NA     valueK
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Hi Kvantour,

I'm new to the Bash scripting but have some knowledge, so if someone can guide me then I will do it myself. I need ideas what to use.

Comment: @pawana, no issues, we all here to learn you could learn here and make other people learn too by sharing the knowledge. I have give a solution could you please try following and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you(tested with GNU `awk`).

```
awk '
/START/{  flag=1  }
/END/{
   num=split(val_label,label," ");
   digit=label[num];
   sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",digit);
   split(val_value,value," ");
   for(i=1;i<=digit;i++){
      sub(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"",label[i]);
      k=i;
      if(i!=label[i]){
         while(k<label[i]){  na=na?na OFS "NA":"NA";k++  };
      value[i]=na OFS value[i]};
   na=k=""};
   for(l=1;l<=digit;l++){  printf("%s%s",value[l],l==digit?ORS:OFS)  };
   delete label;
   delete value;
   val_value=val_label=""
}
flag && /label/{  val_label=val_label?val_label OFS $0:$0  }
flag && /value/{  val_value=val_value?val_value OFS $0:$0  }
'    Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Tested with sample Input_file if you have more conditions then we could have to change it accordingly too.

Comment: Hello Ravinder,

It's working fine! Thanks for the guide.

/pawana

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in python code:

```
with open("testfile.txt","r") as tt, open("output.txt","w") as op:
    lnums = []
    values =[]
    for ll in tt:
        if(ll.split()):

            if(ll.split()[0]=="START"):
                lnums = []
                values =[]

            elif(ll.split()[0]=="END"):
                max = lnums[-1]
                j=0
                for i in range(max):
                    if(lnums[j]==i+1):
                        op.write(values[j]+" ")
                        j=j+1
                    else:
                        op.write("NA ")
                op.write("\n")

            else:
                if("label" in ll):
                    labels = ll.split()
                    lnums = lnums + [int(x[5:]) for x in labels] #extract number from label

                elif("value" in ll):
                    values = values + ll.split()
```